# Conditional string comparison failing for basename/slug

Tags: php, templates, comparison

I am trying to display a particular block of html for one page in particular. I have created a conditional statement that compares the basename of the page to my string.

```
<?php if ( has_tag( 'Sponsor' ) && basename( get_permalink() != 'sponsor-one') ) : // show sponsor's footer if applicable ?>
<div class="sponsor-footer <?php echo basename( get_permalink() ); ?>">
    <p>Our text here</p>
</div>
<?php elseif ( has_tag( 'Sponsor' ) && basename( get_permalink() == 'sponsor-one') ) : // show sponsor one's footer if applicable ?>
<div class="sponsor-footer <?php echo basename( get_permalink() ); ?>">
    <p>Our other text here</p>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

It always outputs the first block of code even when the slug is "sponsor-one".

If I `var_dump( basename( get_permalink() ) );` I get `string(11) "sponsor-one"`, so why is it saying that the basename is not equal to "sponsor-one"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2nd part of the condition seems wrong

`basename( get_permalink() != 'sponsor-one')` should be `basename( get_permalink() ) != 'sponsor-one'`

Please check where the parenthesis ends. Also in your code if that is the only condition, then you can have an `else` statement instead of having another `elseif`.

Comment: It's always a typo isn't it? It's because I originally put the conditional statements in parentheses, then removed the parentheses in the wrong order and it didn't throw an error. Thanks very much.

Comment: That did not throw error as it was a function returning value which will always execute successfully. To be free from such typos specifically in the above condition, you can 1st use the value and then the function output something like 'sponsor-one' != basename( get_permalink() ) or keep the function output in a variable and then compare.